# What is the name of the piano piece Seven of Nine plays?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, music

What is the name of the piano piece that Seven of Nine plays for the holographic Commander Chakotay in Season 7, Episode 18 (*Human Error*) of Star Trek: Voyager?

She plays it for him in a scene where Chakotay asks her to play without the metronome.

It is not the same piece she plays in the opening scene. In that scene she plays *with* a metronome and Chakotay is not present. (As already correctly pointed out, that piece is Chopin's Nocturne Op.72 No.1 in E minor.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The piece played by Seven of Nine in that episode, at Chakotay's request and where he asks her to play without the metronome, is Robert Schumann's "Von fremden Ländern und Menschen" (variously translated as *Of foreign lands and people* or *Of foreign countries and people*) from Scenes Of Childhood (Opus 15, No. 1). That is according to [this link](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Human_Error_(episode)#Background_Information) and it certainly sounds the same.

It's a beautiful piece!

Comment: I don't know why the other (wrong) answers are voted so highly while Arman
s answer isn't. Arman's answer is correct while others are wrong. Seven of nine plays two pieces in that episode. The first piece she plays is Chopin but the second piece with Chakotay is indeed Schumann. All you have to do is just youtube both pieces and listen to them.

Comment: @FixedPoint Because Wikis and I answered first and we got carried away by improving our (wrong) answers. 10 hours later this answer was posted and almost nobody noticed. @ Arman: You can mark your answer as the right one. It would move it in first position - despite the votes.

Answer (score 26):

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Error_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)) that would be [Chopin's Nocturne Op.72 No.1 in E minor](http://www.free-scores.com/PDF_EN/chopin-frederic-nocturne-op-72-no-1-1525.pdf).

It was the first [nocturne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturne) he composed (1827) but it was not published until 1855. With "only" 57 bars it is rather short, since it's played in Andante (~70 bpm)

It was not only used in that episode but also in the movie ["Tombstone"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_(film)) and as the main theme in ["The Secret Garden"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_Garden_(1987_film)).

Comment: Darn, they removed our comments! Now no one will understand all the links!

Comment: @Wikis Yes, my answer now feels sort of... creepy. Was more fun when there was a war going on!

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks :) I'm sorry I missed the debate, must have been a cracker if they removed it!

Comment: .. but that's not the same piece. She plays it well into the episode, when chakotay convinces her to play without the metronome.

Comment: @Arman - then can you indicate in the video (see my question for example links) when it is eg the time stamp? We've both got a lot of upvotes but that's pretty useless if we've answered the wrong question... :)